# What does the @ symbol do when placed in front of indirect?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Help on attempting to use conditional formatting with indirect...

I'm trying to use indirect within conditional formatting.  The formula works works with the yellow format, but not with any other form of or format.

What does the @ symbol do when placed in front of indirect?

What I trying to do is in one cell format the cell anyone 6 categories according to the length of time it has been there…

Less then 0,    0,  0-30,   greater than 30-60, greater than 60-90, greater than 90-365

Any help would be appreciated…

Charles
[INDIRECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwto6.png)

Comment: Here is very easiest way to understand what does `INDIRECT` function does [INDIRECT FUNCTION](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/indirect.html) go through it. I hope it will help.

Comment: the `@` may be related to structured reference and could you please confirm by removing the `@` symbol will your formulas work as usual?